# Having trouble embedding multiple javascript graphs from website in same activity window

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

So basically I have 9 different links to javascript charts generated by Grafana from a data source. I need to embed all of these charts from multiple websites into one android activity window.

Current solution: I used webView and loadData method - loaded all the pages as iframes, binded them to webViews and it's working but I have a problem.

Problem: It takes around 10 seconds for activity to load (I think it's because all the charts are using javascript heavily). I already tried binding a webClient to webView and enable hardware acceleration in Manifest, also tried to enable all the cool HTML5 stuff. Didn't help, it's still loading slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried by loading the data trough Js instead?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show some example?

Comment: Try to load the data trough an AJAX request?

Comment: Solved by getting data (x,y points) in JSON format and then rendering the charts by using chart library....

Comment: Post it as answer then so people now you solved it!